# `markdown-mode` only renders some, not all, LaTeX strings

Tags: latex, html, markdown-mode

I'm using `markdown-mode`.  I followed these instructions to render LaTeX math strings: http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/

I am rendering to HTML with `markdown-export` and `markdown-live-preview-mode`.  Have I assumed incorrectly that these LaTeX expressions can be rendered to HTML?

Simple LaTeX strings render fine:

> then the event ${ \tau \leq n }$ is just

[image]

Any LaTeX string with a function inside does not render:

> with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and

[image]

Extra curly braces do not fix rendering:

> with probability ${\frac{1}{2}}$ and

I think I have the relevant Macports ports installed, and the relevant Emacs packages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how exactly you are rendering the LaTeX fragments. I'm not sure if this is possible with the `markdown` program, but it does work with [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html). To use this in `markdown-mode`, customize `markdown-command` (via `M-x customize-variable`) to `pandoc -s --mathjax`. This assumes you have pandoc installed, of course. There are other options available as well; see the [Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#math-rendering-in-html) for more details.

Comment: This didn't work for me I still can't see latex fragments properly generated nor can I see tables being properly generated. An example is show [here](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/429)

Comment: @KirkWalla we can't help you without details. If you want to open a new question with those details someone might be able to help you work through it.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, I did open a new question with details [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55145/how-to-properly-render-markdown-latex-in-emacs-cli-using-markdown-mode-and-pando)